# How many OpenCL registers has ATI Radeon HD 6750M and 6970M?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I cannot find any information about number of registers in the ATI Radeon HD 6750M and 6970M GPUs. I want to optimize my OpenCL kernels to utilize as many as possimbe processing units, so I need to estimate the maximum number of registers per thread.
Where can I find complete specifications for ATI GPUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed the best OpenCL programming guide of AMD/ATI. [AMD APP OpenCL](http://developer.amd.com/tools/hc/AMDAPPSDK/assets/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf) gives detailed spec for OpenCL-supported ATI/AMD GPUs in order to optimize the code for OpenCL computations. According to this document (Table D.3 and Table D.2), both of these GPUs have 16384 registers (256 KB) per CU (compute unit).

Comment: Thank you, this guide is really the best!